# How to access non final variable in Alert Dialog's onclick listener without making it final

Tags: java, android

```
@Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        String choice="";
        AlertDialog.Builder builder1 = new AlertDialog.Builder(parent.getContext());
        builder1.setMessage("Do you want to accept this vendor's quote?");
        builder1.setCancelable(true);
        builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
             choice= "true" //cant access non final variable
            }
        });
        builder1.setNegativeButton("No",
                new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();
            }
        });

        AlertDialog alert11 = builder1.create();
        alert11.show();
if(choice.equals("true"){
// do something
}

    }
```

How can i access 'choice' variable without making it final or  is there any other way to get to know if user has pressed either on positive button or negative button

Comment: make it `Global` then...

Comment: and do not check this variable immediately after alertdialog was shown. You should check it after it dismisses

Comment: @MD if i declare choice as public static or static in side this listener then its saying only final modifier is permitted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Declare your variable as a field in the class:

```
public class YourClass {
    private String choice;
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The clean way is to make the `onClick` method call a "setter" method in your parent class.

```
public class Activity {
  private boolean choice = false;

...

  //In your method
  builder1.setPositiveButton("Yes",
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
              public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                setChoice(true);
              }
            });

  }

...

  public void setChoice(boolean choice) {
    this.choice = choice;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The variable has to be final, e.g. Eclipse says:

> Cannot refer to a non-final variable choice inside an inner class defined in a different method

Comment: i dont want to make it final as its coded in OnItemClickListener and when this listener catches another event it wont be able to make changes due to 'final'

Answer (score 0):

Declare the variable right outside, just inside the class definition.